# Python ParseError Document is empty

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I'm lost. You won't be able to run the code because of existing files in the directory. Does anyone know why this occurs? Below is the code and the executed error. It runs up to 1900 before stopping. Why 1900? I've run it 5 times, and it's always 1900. I would understand the issue more if it crashed immediately, but it runs and then doesn't half way through?

```
import os
import pandas as pd
#this replace parse_data_live
SCORE_DIR = "data/scores"
box_scores = os.listdir(SCORE_DIR)
box_scores = [os.path.join(SCORE_DIR, f) for f in box_scores if f.endswith(".html")]
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def parse_html(box_score):
    with open(box_score, encoding="utf-8") as f:
        html = f.read()
    #with open(box_score) as f:
        #html = f.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    [s.decompose() for s in soup.select("tr.over_header")]
    [s.decompose() for s in soup.select("tr.thead")]
    return soup


def read_season_info(soup):
    nav = soup.select("#bottom_nav_container")[0]
    hrefs = [a["href"] for a in nav.find_all('a')]
    season = os.path.basename(hrefs[1]).split("_")[0]
    return season


def read_line_score(soup):
    line_score = pd.read_html(str(soup), attrs={'id': 'line_score'})[0]
    cols = list(line_score.columns)
    cols[0] = "team"
    cols[-1] = "total"
    line_score.columns = cols

    line_score = line_score[["team", "total"]]

    return line_score


def read_stats(soup, team, stat):
    df = pd.read_html(str(soup), attrs={'id': f'box-{team}-game-{stat}'}, index_col=0)[0]
    df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="coerce")
    return df


games = []
base_cols = None
for box_score in box_scores:
    soup = parse_html(box_score)

    line_score = read_line_score(soup)
    teams = list(line_score["team"])

    summaries = []
    for team in teams:
        basic = read_stats(soup, team, "basic")
        advanced = read_stats(soup, team, "advanced")

        totals = pd.concat([basic.iloc[-1, :], advanced.iloc[-1, :]])
        totals.index = totals.index.str.lower()

        maxes = pd.concat([basic.iloc[:-1].max(), advanced.iloc[:-1].max()])
        maxes.index = maxes.index.str.lower() + "_max"

        summary = pd.concat([totals, maxes])

        if base_cols is None:
            base_cols = list(summary.index.drop_duplicates(keep="first"))
            base_cols = [b for b in base_cols if "bpm" not in b]

        summary = summary[base_cols]

        summaries.append(summary)
    summary = pd.concat(summaries, axis=1).T

    game = pd.concat([summary, line_score], axis=1)

    game["home"] = [0, 1]

    game_opp = game.iloc[::-1].reset_index()
    game_opp.columns += "_opp"

    full_game = pd.concat([game, game_opp], axis=1)
    full_game["season"] = read_season_info(soup)

    full_game["date"] = os.path.basename(box_score)[:8]
    full_game["date"] = pd.to_datetime(full_game["date"], format="%Y%m%d")

    full_game["won"] = full_game["total"] > full_game["total_opp"]
    games.append(full_game)

    if len(games) % 100 == 0:
        print(f"{len(games)} / {len(box_scores)}")
games_df = pd.concat(games, ignore_index=True)
print(games_df)
games_df.to_csv("nba_games.csv")




#outcome

100 / 8394
200 / 8394
300 / 8394
400 / 8394
500 / 8394
600 / 8394
700 / 8394
800 / 8394
900 / 8394
1000 / 8394
1100 / 8394
1200 / 8394
1300 / 8394
1400 / 8394
1500 / 8394
1600 / 8394
1700 / 8394
1800 / 8394
1900 / 8394
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Martin\PycharmProjects\Dog\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 730, in _build_doc
    r = parse(self.io, parser=parser)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\PycharmProjects\Dog\venv\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 937, in parse
    return etree.parse(filename_or_url, parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 3538, in lxml.etree.parse
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1876, in lxml.etree._parseDocument
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1902, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1805, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1177, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 615, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 725, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 652, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
OSError: Error reading file '': failed to load external entity ""

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Martin\PycharmProjects\Dog\nba game.py", line 52, in <module>
    line_score = read_line_score(soup)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\PycharmProjects\Dog\nba game.py", line 30, in read_line_score
    line_score = pd.read_html(str(soup), attrs={'id': 'line_score'})[0]
  File "C:\Users\Martin\PycharmProjects\Dog\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\PycharmProjects\Dog\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1098, in read_html
    return _parse(
  File "C:\Users\Martin\PycharmProjects\Dog\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 906, in _parse
    tables = p.parse_tables()
  File "C:\Users\Martin\PycharmProjects\Dog\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 222, in parse_tables
    tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\PycharmProjects\Dog\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 738, in _build_doc
    r = fromstring(self.io, parser=parser)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\PycharmProjects\Dog\venv\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 873, in fromstring
    doc = document_fromstring(html, parser=parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\PycharmProjects\Dog\venv\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 761, in document_fromstring
    raise etree.ParserError(
lxml.etree.ParserError: Document is empty

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `OSError: Error reading file '': failed to load external entity ""` Seems that there's an empty file in your list

Comment: Couple things. 1) it doesnt crash at 1900. It actually crashes some where >= 1900. 2) Add a print statement in there of the html. That way you can see at what url it crashes, then you can open that up in the browser and inspect it and see what the issue is. Lastly, it's impossible for anyone to help you if you don't provide everything to reproduce this. If you want help, you'll need to include the html list in `box_scores`

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same project and ran into the same issue.

After running this code, I found 3 empty box scores:

```
for b in box_scores:
    if os.path.getsize(b) == 0: # check for empty files
        print(b)
```

I removed the 3 empty files using the following list comprehension:

```
box_scores = [b for b in box_scores if os.path.getsize(b) != 0]
```

Currently rerunning the code now, will let you know if it works.